# Regex repeating numbers and sequences

Tags: php, regex

Another Regex question. Have spend ages trawling through StackOverflow with no joy.

I need regexs (regexai?) for the following:

- Can’t have more than 4 double numbers in a row. Eg 22334455 fails,
- Can’t have a sequence of numbers longer than or equal to 5 digits. Eg
  12345 or 56789 both fail,
- Must have 4 or more different digits. Eg
  77788778877 fails

I don't expect one expression to fit all, guessing it'll probably be 2/3 required.

Cheers

Comment: If you have no experience with *regexps*, then use a manual loop to iterate over strings and assert patterns, or [`count_chars`](http://php.net/count_chars) even. Checking for `12345`-style patterns is way too much effort (or a dumb preset alternative list) with a regex anyway. (Also good on you for checking other questions beforehand. And this is actually one of the more interesting topics. Yet too many questions in this tag are of the requirement→gimme-code variety; You should still show some attempt or research excerpt.)

Comment: Why You insist on using regex? (Third requirement cannot be accomplished with regex easily) What is the input (only numbers or something more)? Does these requirements have to match all phrase or just a part of it?

Comment: `(?!\d{2}\d{2}\d{2}\d{2})(?=\d*\d*\d*\d*)`

Comment: I spent some time on this but realized it is not at all clear what input you realy have. If the strings only consist of digit sequences, you only need the second and third conditions as you require the string to be smaller than 5 digit long. Please provide real life example strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only requirement, in my opinion which can be solved with a regular expression is the first, with an expression such as this: `((\d)\2){4}`. This will attempt to match a digit and the same digit 4 times (it will look for 4 pairs).

The other requirements, such as checking if a digit is one less than the one the follows it and the last one cannot, to my knowledge be solved with a regular expression.

My recommendation would be to have a method which checks for each requirement and yield a boolean value denoting failure or success. This way at least you will have an idea of what you are doing and would be in a position to maintain the solution should one day the requirements change.

Long story short, what you are after can be achieved through a simple loop and some numerical checks.